# JDBC reading data from database table that contains control characters

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jakarta-ee

I have the following bit of code that reads data from the an Oracle table (Note: This is running on Jdk 1.4.2)

```
ResultSet message = messageStatement.executeQuery(getMsgSql);
String messageData = message.getString("MESSAGE_DATA");
```

The data in the MESSAGE_DATA column contains text but also control characters that separate data elements in the message (i.e (char)31, (char)29) and (char)28) .

What i am finding is that for some reason message.getString() is sometimes truncating the message. I can read the majority of messages but some of them are truncated. Am i supposed to be reading the data using a different method? If so how?

I have tried to use sqlplus to look at the data in the database and it is all there it is just truncated by the message.getString() method. I saw this when i tried to output the result i.e. System.out.println(message.getString()).

Thanks

### Update

I ran an sql query using the length() function in Oracle and length("MESSAGE_DATA") returns 2032 whereas in java message.getString(1).length() returns 2000. Im not sure why this is happening.

### Update

Ok i might be on to something i think. I just tried a newer version of the JDBC driver and it seems to be working. The driver that was being used was an older version that was delivered for the jdk1.4 delivery. Does anyone know why this is the case? And also, does using a newer version of the jdbc driver have any implications especially given the fact that the application is running on JDK 1.4. The oracle version is 10.1.0.3.0

### Update

I am not sure if this is any helpfull but here are the versions of the two JDBC drivers.

The JDBC driver that does not work

```
=====  Database info =====
DatabaseProductName: Oracle
DatabaseProductVersion: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.1.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
=====  Driver info =====
DriverName: Oracle JDBC driver
DriverVersion: 8.0.5.2.0
DriverMajorVersion: 8
DriverMinorVersion: 0
```

The JDBC Driver that does work

```
=====  Database info =====
DatabaseProductName: Oracle
DatabaseProductVersion: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.1.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
=====  Driver info =====
DriverName: Oracle JDBC driver
DriverVersion: 10.2.0.1.0
DriverMajorVersion: 10
DriverMinorVersion: 2
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain the string is "truncated" or are you simply seeing the result the control characters have on the terminal/console? What's the length of the string compared to the data in the db?

Comment: Yes i run an sql query and on sqlplus,  length("MESSAGE_DATA") is returning 2032 whereas in java message.getString(1).length() is returning 2000.

Comment: I'd assume that version `8.x` is most probably de-supported anyway, so by all means go for the 10.x driver.

Comment: Is the version difference going to cause any problems though? ie. the driver is 10.2.0.1 but the database is 10.1? I had a look at oracle site http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html and cant find the driver for 10.1..0.3 They have 10.1.0.2 maybe that is the better option?

Comment: @Ziggy: no problem at all. You can even use a 11.x driver if you want to.

Comment: 8.x driver is pretty old. I remember we used 10x driver on 8x databases, it worked better than 8x driver (some issues with blobs were fixed, if I remember right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: database has a non-default charset. If Java driver is unaware of that charset, it will expect the default (whatever it is), and do a decoding wrong, sometimes possible truncating the string.